# Python command erro 500

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to execute a `subprocess.Popen()` command. But it is returning error 500 when my JavaScript invokes the program via `XmlHttpRequest()`.

The error is:

> GET http://177.55.99.146:8080/autenticacao/autentica?arquivo=[object%20File] 500 (Internal Server Error)

My code:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
def chamaProg(arquivo): 
   p = Popen(['java -Djava.library.path="C:\\Nitgen" -jar C:\\Nitgen\\Busca3-N_java.jar',arquivo], stdin=arquivo, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
   output = p.stdout.read()
   print output   
   return p
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 500 is a server side error, so your "script" is fine. But OMG! why are you using Python to start a Java subprocess that makes a HTTP request....

Comment: But what could be another alternative?

Comment: you can just do the request in Python or just call the java application directly, it really depends on what you are trying to do with the data.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 Error Code is a Server Side Error.  This means that you are likely requesting an action that the server does not know how to handle.  For information on Standard Server Return codes check out [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)